# How can I search of a word in a column in 2 diffrent repositories using one query (MySQL and TYPEORM and nestjs)

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using **MySQL** with **Typeorm** in **nestjs** the latest versions of them and I have these entities:

The shop.entity.ts:

```
@Entity()
export class Shop {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @Column({ unique: true, nullable: false })
  name: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  description: string;

  @Column({ default: "" })
  image_url: string;

  @Column({ default: true })
  is_active: boolean;

  @Column({ default: false })
  is_special: boolean;

  @Column({ nullable: false, default: () => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" })
  created_at: Date;
}
```

offer.entity.ts

```
@Entity()
export class Offer {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  name: string;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  fabric: string;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  code: string;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  start_date: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  end_date: Date;

  @Column({ default: "" })
  description: string;

  @Column({ nullable: false, default: () => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" })
  created_at: Date;
}
```

shop.service.ts
filter query

```
async filter(filter: FilterShopDto) {
const queryBuilder = this.shopRepository
          .createQueryBuilder("shop")
          .where(
            `shop.description LIKE :description`,
            {
              description: filter.description ? `%${filter.description}%` : "%",
            },
          )
          .orderBy("shop.created_at", "DESC")
          .skip(filter.skip)
          .take(filter.take)
}
```

offer.service.ts
offer filter

```
async filter(filter: FilterOfferDto) {
const queryBuilder = this.offerRepository
          .createQueryBuilder("offer")
          .where(
            " offer.description LIKE :description",
            {
              description: filter.description ? `%${filter.description}%` : "%", 
            },
          )
          .orderBy(
            "offer.created_at",
            "DESC",
          )
          .skip(filter.skip)
          .take(filter.take)
}
```

each one of the queries works just fine, but what I wanna do is merge these two queries into one that gets me the search result from the shop and the offer and order the records and apply skip and take on them. **is there any way possible to do it??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TypeORM** enables you to use any queries to your heart's content. using **entityManager.query()** Here is the [documentation](https://typeorm.io/entity-manager-api).